# iMessage access

Tags: messages

We have a 14 year old daughter we are trying to monitor her texting. We use a third party app that captures deleted texts but it’s not real-time not user friendly.  How do I set up our phones wher all of her texts come to us as well?

Comment: There's dozens of questions on this site on this topic and people have offered a variety of answers, including what's offered by your cell provider. Have you searched for those questions and tried any of those products?  Please [edit] your question to include those items so we don't suggest steps that you have already taken. Also include your daughter's device and OS level.

Answer (score 1):

If they are iMessages then you could do it via iCloud. For SMS messaging or if it's over Whatsapp or another instant messenger, you could have a much harder time.

Most half decent services for messaging offer end-to-end encryption so it would be virtually impossible to act as a middle man as you're describing.

You could call your service provider and ask if they have any services for this kind of thing, but keep in the back of your mind - if you can do this to your child's phone, how do you know malicious hackers couldn't be doing the same to you.

This kind of privacy and security is a pretty hot topic at the moment so I think it would be scary if there did happen to be an easy way to accomplish what you are trying.